# Scraping dynamic table in R

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am stuck on a simple web scrape. 
My goal is to scrape Morningstar.com to retrieve the education of the managers associated to a fund name.

First off, let me say that I am not familiar at all with this operation. However, I did my best to provide some code.

For example, consider the following webpage
http://financials.morningstar.com/fund/management.html?t=AALGX&region=usa&culture=en_US

The problem is that the page dynamically loads the section I am targeting, so it doesn't actually get pulled in by read_html()

So what I did was to access to the data loaded in my section of interest.

Specifically, I did:

```
# edit: added packages required
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(stringi)

# original code
tmp_url <- "http://financials.morningstar.com/fund/management.html?t=AALGX&region=usa&culture=en_US"
pg <- read_html(tmp_url)
tmp <- length(html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//script[contains(., 'function loadManagerInfo()')]"))
html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//script[contains(., 'function loadManagerInfo()')]") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      stri_split_lines() %>% 
      .[[1]] -> js_lines

    idx <- which(stri_detect_fixed(js_lines, '\t\t\"//financials.morningstar.com/oprn/c-managers.action?&t='))
    start <- nchar("\t\t\"//financials.morningstar.com/oprn/c-managers.action?&t=")+1
    id <- substr(js_lines[idx],start, start+9)

tab <- read_html(paste0("http://financials.morningstar.com/oprn/c-managers.action?&t=",id,"&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&callback=jsonp1523529017966&_=1523529019244"), options = "HUGE")
```

The object tab contains the information I need.

What I need to do now is to create a dataframe associating to each manager name, his or her manager education.
I could try to do this by transforming my object in a string, then extracting the characters following the word "Education".
Though, this looks extremely inefficient.

I was wondering if anyone can provide some guidance.

Comment: I've added the packages in required, are these the right ones?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I totally forgot to do it.

Comment: do you have a index table of all the links associated with individual funds already? @shazz

Comment: @CarlBoneri I do. I was trying to figure out how to perform this task for one fund and then apply the same operation for all funds. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: No that's what I figured... I'll post a function that takes a URL argument in a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This thing really is a mess - nice work getting the links and downloding the info.

Poking around a lot and taking various detours this is the best I could come up:

## Clean Up

First there is some cleanup to do. Instead of directly downloading and parsing the document in one step we will:

1. download the document as text
2. clean up the text a little to get the JSON
3. parse the JSON
4. extract the HTML item
5. do some further cleaning
6. finally parse the HTML

```
url <- 
  paste0(
    "http://financials.morningstar.com/oprn/c-managers.action?&t=",
    id,
    "&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&callback=jsonp1523529017966&_=1523529019244"
  )

txt <- 
  readLines(url, warn = FALSE)

json <- 
  txt %>% 
  gsub("^jsonp\\d+\\(", "", .) %>% 
  gsub("\\)$", "", .)

json_parsed <- 
  jsonlite::fromJSON(json) 

html_clean <- 
  json_parsed$html %>% 
  gsub("\t", "", .) 

html_parsed <- 
  read_html(html_clean)
```

## First Round of Node Extraction

Next we use some black magic node extraction trickery. Basically the trick goes like this: If we have a node set (the thing you get when using `html_nodes`) we can use further XPath queries to drill down.

The first node set (`cvs`) captures the basic path to the CV entries in the table.

The second node set (`info_tmp`) drills down a little further to get the those part of the CV entries where further information ("Other Assets Managed", "Education", ... etc) is stored.

```
cvs <- 
  html_parsed %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[not(@align='left')]")

info_tmp <- 
  cvs %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "td/table/tbody")
```

## Building up Data.Frame 1

There is little problem with the table. Each CV entry lives in its own table row. For `name`, `from`, `to` and `description` there is always exactly one item per CV entry but for "Other Assets Managed", "Education", ... etc this is not true. 
Therefore, information extraction is done in two parts.

```
df <- 
  cvs %>% 
  lapply(
    FUN = 
      function(x){
        tmp <- 
          x %>% 
          html_nodes(xpath = "th") %>% 
          html_text() %>% 
          gsub("  +", "", .)

        data.frame(
          name = stri_extract(tmp, regex = "[. \\w]+"),
          from = stri_extract(tmp, regex = "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}"),
          to   = stri_extract(tmp, regex = "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}")
        )
      }
  ) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .)

df$description <- 
  info_tmp %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "tr[1]/td[1]") %>% 
  html_text()

df$cv_id <- seq_len(nrow(df))
```

## Building Up Data.Frame 2

Now some more html nodes trickery ... If we use `html_nodes()` the result set of `html_nodes()` we get all matching and none of the none matching nodes. This is a problem since we might get 1, 0 or multiple nodes per node set node basically destroying any information about where those newly selected nodes came from.

There is a solution however: We can use lapply to query each element of an node set independently from the others and therewith preserving information about the original structure.

```
extract_key_value_pairs <- 
  function(i, info_tmp){

    cv_id <-
      seq_along(info_tmp)

    key <-
      lapply(
        info_tmp, 
        function(x){
          tmp <- 
            x %>% 
            html_nodes(xpath = paste0("tr[",i,"]/td[1]")) %>% 
            html_text() 
          if ( length(tmp) == 0 ) {
            return("")
          }else{
            return(tmp)
          }
        }
      )

    value <-
      lapply(
        info_tmp, 
        function(x){
          tmp <- 
            x %>% 
            html_nodes(xpath = paste0("tr[",i,"]/td[2]")) %>% 
            html_text() %>% 
            stri_trim_both() %>% 
            stri_split(fixed = "\n") %>% 
            lapply(X = ., stri_trim_both)

          if ( length(tmp) == 0 ) {
            return("")
          }else{
            return(unlist(tmp))
          }
        }
      )
    df <- 
      mapply(
        cv_id = cv_id, 
        key   = key, 
        value = value,
        FUN = 
          function(cv_id, key, value){
            data.frame(
              cv_id = cv_id,
              key   = key,
              value = value
            )
          },
        SIMPLIFY = FALSE
      ) %>% 
      do.call(rbind, .)

    df[df$key != "",]
  }

df2 <- 
  lapply(
    X        = c(3, 5, 7),
    FUN      = extract_key_value_pairs,
    info_tmp = info_tmp
  ) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .)
```

## Results

```
df 
##                   name       from         to    description cv_id
## 1       Kurt J. Lauber 03/20/2013 03/20/2013 Mr. Lauber ...     1
## 2       Noah J. Monsen 02/28/2018 02/28/2018 Mr. Monsen ...     2
## 3        Lauri Brunner 09/30/2018 09/30/2018 Ms. Brunne ...     3
## 4    Darren M. Bagwell 02/29/2016 02/29/2016 Darren M.  ...     4
## 5     David C. Francis 10/07/2011 10/07/2011 Francis is ...     5
## 6    Michael A. Binger 04/14/2010 04/14/2010 Binger has ...     6
## 7      David E. Heupel 04/14/2010 04/14/2010 Mr. Heupel ...     7
## 8      Matthew D. Finn 03/30/2007 03/30/2007 Mr. Finn h ...     8
## 9         Scott Vergin 03/30/2007 03/30/2007 Vergin has ...     9
## 10 Frederick L. Plautz 11/01/1995 11/01/1995 Plautz has ...    10
## 11    Clyde E. Bartter 01/01/1994 01/01/1994 Bartter is ...    11
## 12    Wayne C. Stevens 01/01/1994 01/01/1994 Stevens is ...    12
## 13      Julian C. Ball 07/16/1987 07/16/1987 Ball is a  ...    13


df2
## cv_id                  key                                   value
##     1 Other Assets Managed                                        
##     2 Other Assets Managed                                        
##     3 Other Assets Managed                                        
##     4        Certification                                     CFA
##     4 Other Assets Managed                                        
##     5        Certification                                     CFA
##     5            Education   M.B.A. University of Pittsburgh, 1978
##     5            Education     B.A. University of Pittsburgh, 1977
##     5 Other Assets Managed                                        
##     6        Certification                                     CFA
##     6            Education    M.B.A. University of Minnesota, 1991
##     6            Education      B.S. University of Minnesota, 1987
##     6 Other Assets Managed                                        
##     7 Other Assets Managed                                        
##     8        Certification                                     CFA
##     8            Education   B.A. University of Pennsylvania, 1984
##     8            Education     M.B.A. University of Michigan, 1990
##     8 Other Assets Managed                                        
##     9        Certification                                     CFA
##     9            Education    M.B.A. University of Minnesota, 1980
##     9            Education             B.A. St. Olaf College, 1976
##     9 Other Assets Managed                                        
##    10            Education      M.S. University of Wisconsin, 1981
##    10            Education    B.B.A. University of Wisconsin, 1979
##    10 Other Assets Managed                                        
##    11        Certification                                     CFA
##    11            Education M.B.A. Western Reserve University, 1964
##    11            Education      B.A. Baldwin-Wallace College, 1953
##    11 Other Assets Managed                                        
##    12        Certification                                     CFA
##    12            Education         M.B.A. University of Wisconsin,
##    12            Education             B.B.A. University of Miami,
##    12 Other Assets Managed                                        
##    13        Certification                                     CFA
##    13            Education        B.A. Kent State University, 1974
##    13            Education   J.D. Cleveland State University, 1984
##    13 Other Assets Managed
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a concise and elegant use of the rvest package, and it provides more or less what I was looking for.
However, your script does not returns the field education: e.g. David Francis,  M.B.A. University of Pittsburgh, 1978, B.A. University of Pittsburgh, 1977.
I am not very acquainted with the rvest package, otherwise, I would suggest how to modify your script to get the correct field.
If you can provide the requested solution, I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Tricky - here you go. I rebuild the answer and put in some node set trickery: (1) using `html_nodes()` on the result of `html_nodes()` and (2) `lapply()`-ing `html_nodes()` on node sets produced by `html_nodes()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution, as this is not an area I have worked with before. However, with brute force you can probably get the table, assuming you have a list of rules that can parse the text to a data frame.

Thought I'd share what I have though

```
# get the text
f <- xml_text(tab)

# split up, this bit is tricky..
split_f <- strsplit(f, split="\\\\t", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
split_f <- strsplit(split_f, split="\\\\n", perl=TRUE)
split_f <- unlist(split_f)
split_f <- trimws(split_f)

# find ones to remove
sort(table(split_f), decreasing = T)[1:5]
split_f <- split_f[split_f!="—"]
split_f <- split_f[split_f!=""]

# manually found where to split
keep <- split_f[2:108]

# text looks ok, but would need rules to extract the rows in to a data.frame
View(keep)
```

Comment: It definitely makes things easier to manipulate this object. Thank you very much for sharing. I will try to work on your code and post my solution. Meanwhile, let's see if someone comes up with a different idea.

Comment: No worries, hoping someone does as I'm interested in seeing if there is a better way too :)